# Fastest way to get minimum Jaccard-Coefficient in networkx

Tags: python, networkx, minimum

I have a graph in networkx and need to get the edge with the minimum Jaccard-Similarity.
I am searching for the most efficient way to do that, because I have to do it multiple times.

I tried to create a dictionary like

`J={(jj[0], jj[1]): jj[2] for jj in nx.jaccard_coefficient(G, G.edges())}`

`min(J, key=J.get)`

this is high in time and needs a lot of memory

as well as to just calculate the minimum entry by

`min(nx.jaccard_coefficient(G, G.edges()), key=lambda tup: tup[2])`

This needs much more time than the previous version. Is there any way to do it more efficient?